# Table of Contents issue in document

Tags: table-of-contents

I am new to latex, During writing my thesis, I have come to a stage where I have to add a lot of `\subsections`,`\subsubsections`,`\subsubsubsections`. What I would like to show numbering scheme in the chapters. but I do not like to show the numbering of subsubsubsections in the Table of contents. I just would like to show main heading in table of contents. But my table of contents showing each subsections and `\paragraph` in the table of content.

Response will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`in the preamble makes the table of contents display up to the `\subsection` level. Chapters have level 0, sections have level 1, &c.

Comment: Which document class do you use?

Answer (score 2):

The table of contents (TOC) as a default show only up to level 3. unless you are using a custom class.
Nonetheless, if you want to modify the appearance of the TOC, follow the below script

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
```

- The tocdepth option >> refers to the Table of Contents (TOC) and the option of modifying the appearance of how many levels to be shown.
- {2} >> refers to how many levels you want to be included.

  ---

If you want to increase the number of your headers (sections and subsections), follow the below script

```
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

- Likewise, the secnumdepth option >> refers to the sectioning number (sec) and the option of modifying the appearance of how many levels to be numbered.
- {3} >> refers to the numerical level of the deepest sectioning units showing up in the TOC.

---

---

Now, to know where you should include these scripts into your code.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Some chapter}
\section{Some section}
\subsection{Some subsection}
\subsubsection{Some subsubsection}
Text ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: the description of "referring to how many levels" included in TOC is a bit wrong: in `article` class, `\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}` allows **2** levels: _parts_, and _sections_. But in `report` class it allows **3** levels because there is also _chapters_. It is more accurate to say simply that the `tocdepth` setting is the numerical level of the deepest sectioning units showing up in the TOC.

Comment: yes, thank you for your modification. I will update the answer